# Is this a comma splice: <Independent clause>, I know

Tags: punctuation, commas, comma-splices

Examples:

> - It's cold, I know.
> - She's awesome, I know.

Are these comma splices? If not, what is the name of the *I know* clause?

Is there a name for the whole structure?

Comment: It's just a stylistic variation on the more normal sequence *"I know it's cold"*. It's definitely not a "comma splice", which basically means trying to use a comma instead of a full stop to separate two sentences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you invert the normal order of the sentence

> I know it's cold.

you need a comma to make the sense clear:

> It's cold, I know.

So while these appear to be two independent clauses, the first is actually a relative clause with an omitted *that*. Here is how the sentence would read if we were to put the *that* back in.

> I know *that* it's cold.

And if we were to invert that, we would have

> That it's cold, I know.

But that sounds a little stilted to the modern ear, so we just say

> It's cold, I know.

Comment: +1 Incidentally, the inversion does shift the emphasis from "it's cold" to "I know".

Answer (score 5):

In those examples, *I know* is a ‘tail’, a feature of speech which reinforces what is being said.

Comment: +1 You have put it better, what I was trying to express in my comment above.

Comment: @Kris: It's a term used in functional grammar, along with 'head' for a similar feature at the start of an utterance.